# Magento 2: create listing grid using ui component without database

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

How to create a listing grid using UI component in the backend without a database ?

Comment: do u want to get data from array??

Comment: anyway, Just don't use the database, please give me a solution. Thank for reply.

Comment: please Check My Answer......

Answer (score 0):

in Your

> Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\DataProvider.php

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http;
use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider;

/**
 * Class DataProvider
 */
class DataProvider extends AbstractDataProvider
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AddFieldToCollectionInterface[]
     */
    private $addFieldStrategies;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AddFilterToCollectionInterface[]
     */
    private $addFilterStrategies;

    /**
     * Media path to extension images
     *
     * @var string
     */

    private $collectionFactory;

    /**
     * Media path to extension images
     *
     * @var string
     */

    private $saveImage;
    /**
     * Construct
     *
     * DataProvider constructor.
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        Http $request,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->request               = $request;
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Preparing Collection For Grid
     *
     * @return Array
     */

    public function getCollection()
    {
        //Put Your Data in this Variable
        $data  = 
        //Default Objects
        $pagesize    = intval($this->request->getParam('paging')['pageSize']);
        $pageCurrent = intval($this->request->getParam('paging')['current']);
        $pageoffset  = ($pageCurrent - 1) * $pagesize;
        return [
            'totalRecords' => count($data),
            'items'        => array_slice($data, $pageoffset, $pageoffset + $pagesize),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Return Prepared Data To Admin Grid
     *
     * @return AbstractDataProvider
     */

    public function getData()
    {
        if (!$this->getCollection()) {
            $this->getCollection();
        }
        return $this->getCollection();
    }

    /**
     *  Adding Filters To Grid Collection
     *
     */

    public function addFilter(\Magento\Framework\Api\Filter $filter)
    {
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter($filter);
    }

    /**
     * Adding Order To Grid Collection
     *
     */

    public function addOrder($field, $direction)
    {
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addSortOrder($field, $direction);
    }

    /**
     * Set Limit To Admin Collection
     *
     */

    public function setLimit($offset, $size)
    {
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->setPageSize($size);
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->setCurrentPage($offset);
    }
}
```

Now in

> Vendor\Module\view\adminhtml\ui_component\frontname_module_controller.xml

```
<argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\DataProvider.</argument>
        </argument>
```

**Hope this will help You**

Comment: Please give me full solution. Thank you.

Comment: what type of data you want to show in Grid

Comment: simply text. I just need a grid.

Comment: ho much coloums do u have  how mays rows you want then i can give you a Good solution

Comment: maybe 5 columns.

Comment: please let me know All of them

Comment: https://prnt.sc/p1jpoa please check it.

Comment: I am waiting for your answer. Please let me know if you are helping me.

Comment: i will write answer as soon as possibe